# Is it more efficient to code a UI or use Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

So after having read a few different Big Nerd Ranch texts, as well as seen Paul Haddad of Tweetbot fame more or less say that he doesn't use Interface Builder, I've come to the conclusion that for one reason or another, there's something wrong with it?

I personally find myself gravitating toward Interface Builder solely due to my background with Visual Basic. It's easier, it's faster, and just (for me) far more pleasant to work with.

In the end, though, my question is this: **Is there some reason due to efficiency (either through performance of the final app or in the development process) that developers gravitate toward programmatically designed UI's over the Interface Builder-generated counterpart?**

Thank you.

Comment: My 20 cents worth...Not performance as far as I know, probably more preference.    
One situation where is better to have it in code is if you refactor or change something e.g. its easier to do a search and find/replace which is not possible for links created in the GUI. have to go in delete and relink with new name...
p.s. You may also find as the next gen of developers comes through the ranks that the percentage might change ;-)

Comment: I gotcha, that definitely seems to be a lot more efficient coding-wise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder can be fiddly at times, and until recently you couldn't do anything remotely complex with it in terms of laying out UI elements relative to one another. Since you'd have to dip down to code to do that, many people just do everything in code.

However, with the advent of AutoLayout and its amazing integration with Interface Builder, that may change.

Comment: And this is why I posed the question. I don't want to fall into bad practices by using Interface Builder, only to find out that it's not the way to go. Popular opinion of it seemed to be changing until Haddad posted something snarky on his Twitter feed the other day.

Answer (score -1):

I personally feel that you can manage your code better by coding the UI yourself.
Interface builders can be used to build GUIs quickly, and allows you to experiment without having to know the intricate details of all the GUI components supported by your pl.
Best approach would be to mix these two approaches, build quickly using the interface builder, then move the code around as you like.

Comment: Are there any specific benefits to one over the other? Laggier interfaces when using the IB-generated stuff, etc.?